# How can I rig a scrollbar to appear in the center of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of navigation links that are styled to float alternating on the left and right sides of their parent, with a gap down the centre. The issue is that, on smaller screens, some of the links are hidden as a result. The parent container (a fixed sidebar) as a whole does not scroll, and I would prefer to avoid having to make the entire sidebar scroll. The links' CSS code is below:

```
#links {
            margin: 10px 0;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        a.sidebarlink {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            background-color: rgb(87,10,79);
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 43%;
            max-height: 17px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow: none;
            margin: 2px 0px;
        }
        a.sidebarlink:hover {
            animation: sidebarlink 0.4s;
            -webkit-animation: sidebarlink 0.4s;
            border-width: 5px !important;
        }
        #links a:nth-child(2n-1) {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
            border-left: 0px solid white;
            text-align: right;
        }
        #links a:nth-child(2n) {
            float: right;
            clear: right;
            border-top-left-radius: 6px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
            border-left: none;
            border-right: 0px solid white;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 2px 0px 2px 7px;
        }
```

So, the question is... without too much hassle, can I rig a scrollbar to appear in the center? The page is a simple Tumblr blog ([here](http://dawnsblade.tumblr.com/)). The links in the sidebar on the left are arranged as described, if you need to see what I'm talking about.

If necessary, I can make changes to the markup, but I want a single scrollbar, instead of dividing the container down the center and ending up with two scrollbars.

Although I think it unlikely to be possible, I would *prefer* it to be CSS-only. If at all possible, I would suspect it would most likely use the webkit scrollbar classes, and thus only be visible to Chrome users.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## Update: non-JS method

Based on the same markup as below:

Put the scrollbar on the left hand side:

```
#right {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left; /* override direction */
    right: -20px;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjx2v/1/**

---

Here's my idea:

Allow both columns to have a scrollbar but position the rightmost column so that the scrollbar is not visible.

Then use JS to resize the columns to be equal.

Finally add a scroll event to the columns to keep them inline.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="column">
        <p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="column">
        <p>right</p><p>right</p><p>right</p><p>right</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.column {
    height: 100%;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 1%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
}

#right {
    right: -20px; /* Hide the right-most scrollbar */
}
```

### JQuery

```
var column = $('.column');
var left = $('#left');
var right = $('#right');

// Find the maximum height of the columns
var maxH = Math.max(left.height(), right.height());

// Set columns to same height
column.height(maxH);

column.scroll(function() {
    right.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    left.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjx2v/**